# How to install WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0 as the KeyManager of WSO2 Api Manager 1.9.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

WSO2 Identity server 5.1.0 was just released and I want to configure it as the Key Manager of WSO2 Api Manager 1.9.1.

I am following this [guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.0.0+with+API+Manager+1.9.1) but I'm stuck on the features installation. I am using the following P2 Repository.

http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/wilkes/

The problem is that the required features are not listed. Is the API Manager 1.9.1 not compatible with WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0? Or is there any other P2 repository with the needed features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that the required features are not listed. Is the API
>   Manager 1.9.1 not compatible with WSO2 Identity Server 5.1.0?

No, Both are not compatible. API Manager 1.9.1 is based on carbon kernel 4.2.0 and IS 5.1.0 is based on kernel 4.4.3. So you can't install API Manager 1.9.1 Key Manager feature into IS 5.1.0.

We will be releasing API Manager 1.10.0 by January 1 week, after that you should be able to install API Manager 1.10.0 Key Manager feature on IS 5.1.0

Comment: Hi, indeed API Manager 1.10.0 was released, anyway when I try to install key manager features on the IdentityServer, the KeyManager for API Manager 1.10.0 is not listed. I tried using the turing and wilkes repo but with no success.

Comment: @Michael, we are in process of updating it. wilkes is supposed to used.

Comment: @Michael, You can use this repo [http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/chamilaa/apim-1.10.0-rc4/p2-repo/] for the development purposes. We will release the feature repo this week

Comment: I managed to install the API Key Manager feature using the repo you indicates me, however in the guide that explains the key manager feature installation, it is said that I also have to install the  "Registry Extensions Feature -" but I wasn' t able to find it. Is this feature stills needed or can it be found in other repo? Thanks!

[https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.1.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+1.10.0]

Comment: Check teh updated documentation : https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+5.1.0+with+API+Manager+1.10.0